# return query from psql function based on function arguments

Tags: postgresql

I have a function in postgresql which returns query based on the input supplied:

```
create or replace function func(last_month date, arg1 varchar default 'any')
returns table(id bigint, start_date date, end_date date) as $$  
begin
 if arg1 = 'multiple' then
        SELECT DISTINCT id, (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date as start_date,
        last_month as end_date
        FROM table
        WHERE month BETWEEN (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date
        AND last_month
        and month >= '2017-09-01'
        AND activity >= 5;
 else
        SELECT DISTINCT id, (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date as start_date,
        last_month as end_date
        FROM table
        WHERE month BETWEEN (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date
        AND last_month
        and month >= '2017-09-01' 
 end if;
end; $$ language sql;
```

However when I run it, it gives me the following error :

```
syntax error at or near "if"
```

I have checked returning only integer for testing purposes and it works and syntax appears to be fine. How can I return different query results from a function based on the given input.

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL, if you want something like that you need to use [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) (where you will need RETURN QUERY instead)

Comment: I tried to return query like this : 
if device_type = 'computer' then
   return query 
  SELECT DISTINCT panelist_id, (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date as start_date,
        last_month as end_date
        FROM mdb.smart_validation
        WHERE month BETWEEN (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date
        AND last_month
        and month >= '2017-09-01' -- first day of data in P2
        AND steady IS TRUE AND underage IS false
        AND pc_activity >= 5; 
 end if;
but doesnot seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve in he following way:

```
        create or replace function func(last_month date, arg1 varchar default 'any')
        returns table(id bigint, start_date date, end_date date) as $BODY$
        begin
         case arg1 
         when arg1 = 'multiple' then
                return query
                SELECT DISTINCT id, (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date as start_date,
                last_month as end_date
                FROM table
                WHERE month BETWEEN (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date
                AND last_month
                and month >= '2017-09-01'
                AND activity >= 5;
         else
                return query  
                SELECT DISTINCT id, (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date as start_date,
                last_month as end_date
                FROM table
                WHERE month BETWEEN (last_month - interval '1 year' + interval '1 month')::date
                AND last_month
                and month >= '2017-09-01';
         end case;
         end; 
         $BODY$ language  plpgsql;
```